# Removing characters in file names with Rstudio

Tags: r

First time posting here, with limited experience in R and programming in general. I am looking for a way to rename .jpg files from this **SITE_NA_MEXX_YYYY_MM_DD_hh_mm_ss.jpg** to **SITE_NA_MEXX_YYYY_MM_DD_hhmmss.jpg** .

Is this something that can be done? If yes, what function should I use for this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You might like to look at the tidyverse package stringr, and creating a regular expression (regex) to find the characters you want to remove.

Comment: Have you tried something already? The key feature of Stack is helping each other by guidance, not by solving the problem from scratch.

Comment: I will try the stingr package as proposed by Mark Neal. Didn't have time to try yet.